# Practice in managing session in modern mobile application

Tags: android, ios, cordova, session, cookies

I am a web developer and I have learnt from college how to make use of SESSION (more precisely COOKIES) in managing user session. However, when it comes to mobile application, I am confused about how I should implement the system to ensure a secure system while following with the normal practice of an application.

The first thing I am confused is how should I store the session in application. For example in PhoneGap it does not have COOKIES and have to use local storage to simulate COOKIES behavior. I have asked some friends who are in the field of developing native application. They also mentioned in Android they use sharedpreferences and iOS with similar techniques to store user data most of the time.

1. Does it means that in mobile application I should not use COOKIES and should shift the management of session data to the application level instead? Should I store the session in the application storage? This is the first thing I would like to ask.

The second thing is about the session renewal. For a website, a common (and simplified) session verification routine would be like this: whenever a user request a new page, it will first verify the session provided by the user. Then the old session is renewed, and stored in COOKIES. Next time the user will request the page with new session. And if the session expired, the user is redirected to login again.

However, this may not 100% suit with how the world of applications look like nowadays. At least I seldom (actually never from my experience) got logout completely from the application (examples like Facebook, Dropbox, Instagram). I am not quite sure about how their session works. But by observing this behavior, it seems to imply that there isn't a session expiration policy there. This is where I got confused because from I learnt in security course or OWASP this should be a security threat.

2. So here comes the second thing I want to ask: In industrial practice how is the session expiration policy designed in mobile application environment? Does a session last until next time the user open the application again? Moreover, As a developer, how should I design the session such that is guarantees the security while we will not create bad UX? For example a user will definitely be unhappy if he/she has to login again every time he/she does not use the application for few days.

Of course security is a big topic and it is impossible to mention every details in one single answer, but an overall picture and maybe some materials I can start digging into would solve my questions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have experience with banking apps, we store a session key (manually) at login that is used to verify each webservice call, the server handles whether that key is valid or not and if not returns you a logout response which will cause you to get booted out of the app to login screen (like how you mentioned, standard stuff). we also have a timer that will auto logout if there is inactivity in the app (and server side, invalidating the session). So for more higher security apps, the user would get logged out much more often than say, facebook, where you arent going to lose your livelihood (most likely) if your facebook account was compromised.

So it really depends what you need. Facebook relies on advertising for revenue, so wants its users to be able to get into their app without any hassle to get the most views (sacrificing security, but i guess on a mobile phone, you are at least behind a fingerprint or passcode anyway for some form of authentication, even if its not facebook themselves doing it). while a banking apps priority is security, so forcing the user to login every time etc (and 2fa on top of that).